# How to detect if a line is coinciding with another figure?

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++, geometry

I'm trying to make a program to find the shortest path between 2 points.

What I've come up with is to connect the start point to ALL the vertices of every shape. Each of those points will be connected to all other points - thereby forming a sort of tree. In case of circular shapes - the line will be up to a point where it forms a tangent to the circle or arc(since that's the shortest path around the object). However those lines that pass through other objects are disposed off. The remaining paths are subjected to *A** search.

But now how do I make the program identify the lines that pass through other figures? I'm using visual c++, so i can draw shapes in the client area by passing certain coordinates to the respective functions (`eg LineTo(21,23)`) . How will it know when a line is entering into another figure?
[image]

Comment: you need a kind of ray tracer :-)

Comment: @ISTB  ray tracer, line tracer - same thing isn't it? So how DO i trace a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straightforward algorithm taking into account what you've done so far:

1. For every shape store all vertices in an array (or list) in order they appear on the shape (clockwise or counter-clockwise doesn't make a difference). This allows you to easily iterate over edges of any given object, because edges are in that case **(P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>)**, **(P<sub>2</sub>, P<sub>3</sub>)**, ... **(P<sub>N</sub>, P<sub>1</sub>)** where **N** is the number of vertices.
2. For every line you want to check if it collides with any object iterate over all edges you've denoted and if line you're checking is crossing any edge - line collides with given object.

Checking crossing of the line with edge is a geometry problem. If bounding-points of line we are checking are **P<sub>1</sub>=(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>)** and **P<sub>2</sub>=(x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>)**, and bounding points of edge are **P<sub>3</sub>=(x<sub>3</sub>,y<sub>3</sub>)** and **P<sub>4</sub>=(x<sub>4</sub>,y<sub>4</sub>)** then you should solve the linear system:

> **(x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>) y + (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>) x = x<sub>1</sub> y<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>2</sub> y<sub>1</sub>** ,
>   **(x<sub>4</sub> - x<sub>3</sub>) y + (y<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>4</sub>) x = x<sub>3</sub> y<sub>4</sub> - x<sub>4</sub> y<sub>3</sub>** .

After getting a value for **(x, y)** you should check that it is on parts between bounding-points on both lines (line we're checking and the edge). If that is true your lines cross each other.

**Note:** You can improve running time by not iterating over every object's edges when you are checking for collision, but only over those objects that are in the path of the line. This could be accomplished for example by calculating minimal rectangle that contains every object, and checking if your line passes through the rectangle, dismissing the object from further checking if it doesn't.

Comment: I don't understand the equation `(x1 - x0) y + (y0 - y1) x = x0 y1 - x1 y0` - how do you get that? Also what are `x0` and  `y0` ?

Comment: @Ghost That was an error on my part... fixed it. It is an equation of a line determined by two points; and having two of those means you have linear system, solution to which gives you point of intersection of two lines.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _bounding points of vertex_. Isn't a vertex just one point? Which makes it just one coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish two cases :

Either the line is entering a figure through another line. In that case, the easiest way is to represent your lines (including the border of your obstacles) by their equations (they would look like `a*x + b*y +c = 0`). Then deciding whether or not two lines intersect is quite a simple matter :

- Two lines ax+by+c=0 and dx+ey+f=0 intersect if and only if they are not parallel, i.e iff a*e-b*d != 0
- Then you have to check whether or not the intersection point of these two lines is inside the segments which you actually consider. The intersection point have coordinates :

  - y = ( cd - af ) / (ae - db)
  - x = ( bf - ec ) / (ae - db)
- The only remaining task is to check whether or not these x and y belong to the segment (if they are within the intervals defining the segment)
  And you repeat this operation for all segments defining you obstacles.

If you have circles, it becomes trickier (this is why you usually only consider polygons as obstacles), but basically it is the same idea :
- You have a line ax+by+c=0 and a circle (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2 (a circle of center (a,b) and radius r). Then you have to determine whether they intersect, the point of intersection and if it belongs to the segment which you consider. I'll leave the calculs to you.

If you are interested in different methods for finding a path between two points, with obstacles, there are other algorithms which you can use, although these will not provide you with the shortest path, but only with a path :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

The interest of those algorithm compared to the visibility diagram you're building is that these two works in whatever dimension you are : if you want to upgrade your algorithm to  dimensions, your algorithm will have a higher complexity (it will take more time to find a path) then these two and will not yield the shortest path.

Comment: I'm not really understanding how you get `y = ( cd - af ) / (ae - db)` .

Comment: You can have  a relation between x and y thanksto the second equation : dx+ey+f=0 thus x = ( - f - ey ) / d (suppose d not null)
Then you insert that x in ax+by+c=0, a * (- f - ey) / d + by + c = 0, y ( bd - ae ) / d = af / d - c, and finally y = (cd - af) / (ae - bd)